# Inserting Multiple selected Listbox items into the same cell in SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, for-loop, listbox

I want to insert multiple list box items into a a cell In SQL table with a comma dividing the items. The code posted below will only add the first selected item within a listbox. Hence If you select 2 or 10 items the first one u selected will be Inserted into the table. The for loop is my problem, I need to get all the selected values. 
Thanks

```
        protected void pg_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        using (SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand mycmd = mycon.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (textbox_make.Text == string.Empty || textbox_number.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('The Make/Model and Number must be Entered')", true);
                }
                else
                {

                    string str = "";

                    for (int i=0; i<= listbox_software.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        str = listbox_software.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    }

                    mycon.Open();
                    mycmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_PG (Model, PGNumber, AssetNo, Area, Owner,IPAddress, SerialNo, OSVersion, Memory, Software) " +
                                        "Values ('" + textbox_make.Text + "' , '" + textbox_number.Text + "' , '" + textbox_asset.Text + "' , '" + drop_area.Text + "' , '" + drop_owner.Text + "' , '" + textbox_ip.Text + "' " +
                                                ", '" + textbox_serial.Text + "' , '" + textbox_os.Text + "' , '" + textbox_memory.Text + "' ,  '" + str + "')";

                    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    PopulateGridView();

                    lblsuscessmessage.Text = "Selected Record Added";
                    lblerrormessage.Text = "";


                    textbox_make.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_number.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_asset.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_ip.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_serial.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_os.Text = string.Empty;
                    textbox_memory.Text = string.Empty;


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: read up on SQL Injection when you get a chance.. if you want multiple items inserted into a single row, you should read up on how to use `string.Join()` method along with `String.Format()`  method inside your loop look up what the `+=` is used for and what it means, also you need some sort of data separator / delimiter to when concat strings.. look at string builder class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer.

```
                        // To access checkbox list item's value //
                    string total = "";
                    foreach (ListItem listItem in listbox_software.Items)
                    {
                        if (listItem.Selected)
                        {
                            total =  total + "[" + listItem.Value + "][ " + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    string str = total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Create a string array of selected items and then use string.join:

```
    var selection = listbox_software.SelectedItems
        .Cast<string>()
        .ToArray();
    var str = string.Join(",", selection);
```

Comment: The selectedItems dose not work, i was previously trying to use it. Is there any reason you know of that selecteditems would not work. Its shows a red line beneath it.

Comment: You may need to cast to the data type you have data bound the listbox to (instead of string)